# How can I remove the exercise number?

Tags: exercises

I do not want to see "Exercise 1 find", I want only just "find":

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}
\begin{document}
\section{excercise}
\begin{Exercise}[title=find]
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Exercise}[title=search]
\end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine `\ExerciseHeaderNB` (the number of the exercise) and `\ExerciseName` (the word "Exercise") with nothing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeaderNB}{}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{}
\begin{document}
\section{excercise}
\begin{Exercise}[title=find]
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Exercise}[title=search]
\end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help me with another question?

Comment: Hello,@CarLaTeX
I already uploaded the question, it's the same question as the previous one but in that code, help me please.